# Conflicting advice on using Azure AD Graph API over MS Graph with Active Directory B2C

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

On this article below, below is mentioned

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-faqs

> " Consider using the Graph API for user migration ..."

However, when I clicked the link provided below

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet

> "You must use the Azure AD Graph API to manage users in an Azure AD
>   B2C directory"

However, the link below has different recommendation:

> "we recommend the use of Microsoft Graph over Azure AD Graph, as
>   Microsoft Graph is where we are investing for Microsoft cloud
>   services."

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aadgraphteam/2016/07/08/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph/

My question is that which one, Azure AD Graph, or MS Graph, to use when using AD B2C for:

1 User Migration

2 Manage users

3 etcs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, [you must use Azure AD Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet) to manage users in an Azure AD B2C tenant, since Microsoft Graph doesn't support a few of the user properties (including the **creationType** property) that are used by Azure AD B2C.

[This Microsoft Graph or the Azure AD Graph article](https://dev.office.com/blogs/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph) indicates that the current gap between the Microsoft Graph and Azure AD Graph APIs for managing users in an Azure AD B2C tenant.