# Microsoft Graph or Active Directory Graph for Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I must build a dashboard with users in our Azure AD B2C tenant. Which graph api is the best to use (Microsoft Graph or Active Directory Graph)?

Regards
Stefan

Answer (score 1):

You could find the same answer from the [nzpcmad's link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54507144/conflicting-advice-on-using-azure-ad-graph-api-over-ms-graph-with-active-directo?noredirect=1&lq=1).

> You must use the Azure AD Graph API to manage users in an [Azure AD B2C
>   directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet).

And you could also find the related reason why cannot use the Microsoft Graph API from [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aadgraphteam/2016/07/08/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph/).
[image]